# Intel® Desktop Board DG31PR,can i add Transcend 2GB DDR2 RAM (JM667QLU-2G)

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have a PC with below mentioned configuration

- DG31PR Intel board
- Core 2 Duo Processor
- Transend DD2 667 1 GB JetRam , JM667QLJ-1G, 240P DDR2 DIMM (128M*64) (64Mx8 DDR2 667 5-5-5) [LM]

I am planing to upgrade the RAM to increase the performance/speed.

I searched for the Transend RAM with same series JM667QLJ-2G, but not found in flipkart/amazon. Only JM667QLU-2G available will it support my DG31PR intel board? I have bought it.

Can I use it with existing 1GB Ram + 2 GB RAM (my board supports MAX 4GB, 2 slots)?

Comment: They are identical.

Answer (score 0):

If RAM modules have the right format (both are DDR2 here), just go trial and error. Main board manuals typically only list a limited set of trested modules, but these are not limited to be the only ones working properly.

Worst case the system won't boot properly until you change everything back.

Keep in mind that using different RAM modules will disable dual channel mode (if supported) slowing it down. Again this is something to simply try. If you notice the slowdown, grab a second 2GB module and drop the 1GB one.